# How to correctly retrieve int value from firebase realtime database to textview?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have got two values in my database under child: name and score.

To fetch name I used this line:

```
String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
```

Then display to TextView as:

```
tv1.setText(name)
```

This works well.

Then the score is my problem, it is an integer as it is posted to the database. I tried to retrieve it as:

```
int name = (int) dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue();
```

Then display it as:

```
tv1.setText(score)
```

My app is crashing and this is because of the int line for retrieving score. How can i correct this line, or what is the best way to retrieve integers?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: "My app is crashing" Please edit your question to include: 1) the exact error message and its complete stack trace from the logcat output, 2) a single code snippet that we can run to reproduce the problem. Right now we have no way to know how the four lines are related to each other. 3) The JSON that your are reading (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 4) The code that reads the snapshot.

Comment: What type is the `score` property in the database?

Comment: Without the additional information we asked for, it is impossible to help here. I'm voting to close this question for lacking enough debug information.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue:

```
int name = dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue(Integer.class);
```